# Creating an Instante Messenger using XMPP and C#.NET

Tags: c#, asp.net, xmpp, instant-messaging

I've been trying to create an Instant Messaging application in my ASP.NET site using C#. I came to know about [XMPP](http://www.xmpp.org) which is a protocol used for instant messaging by GChat. I was wondering how to implement it in my ASP.NET application. Any insights provided on this will be very much appreciated.

Thank you.

NLV

Comment: Maybe this is of help: http://xmpp.org/software/libraries.shtml#csharp

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The thing about the C# libraries is that most of them are closed-source or licensed.  I've found MatriX (used to be agsXMPP) to be the best in terms of what it can do (developer license might be a bit steep though).  Jabber.net would probably be a good choice too.

It's not for the faint of heart.  Building out a client might be ok but building a component or deploying a server caused me no end of headaches.  Understanding how it works first might be the best approach.  There is a book called "XMPP: The Definitive Guide" that I found really useful.

Comment: You are right about the licensing and pricing of the available libraries. As you said i need to go in and out of the technology to build a component.

Comment: You might not have to, it depends on what you want to implement.  If it's just chat, I think you will be ok with just choosing a server and using BOSH.  If you are trying to push messages from your application through XMPP then you will need to delve into the component side.

A note about the Javascript book recommended below: I purchased it, but had to give up almost immediately as I couldn't get any of the code to actually work.  The author didn't reply to the forum posts about it until a few months later, but I still had problems.  YMMV

See the thread here:
http://tinyurl.com/3xscwl4

Answer (score 0):

Check out this excellent book, should have what you need to implement your IM app

http://www.wrox.com/WileyCDA/WroxTitle/Professional-XMPP-Programming-with-JavaScript-and-jQuery.productCd-0470540710.html

Comment: Does this book deal with creating and deploying an XMPP server?